# the split decision amounted to a reassertion of centrism

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "centrism" mean here? Cambridge Dictionary defines it as "the fact that the stated thing is the main interest" and I have no clue what it means in the context below.

My best guess for the time being is that it means that Federal government controls anything the country.  Not sure I am on the right track or not.

> In a time of legitimate hacking fears, there were no reports of foreign interference. Our defenses held. On top of all that, the coutcome was moderate: for all the strife and stress of recent years, **the split decision amounted to a reassertion of centrism**.

> Source:  [Twitter](https://twitter.com/JonHaidt/status/1330871922083688448)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrism#:~:text=In%20politics%2C%20centrism%20is%20a,the%20left%20or%20the%20right.

Comment: Cambridge's definition is for the suffix [**-centrism**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/centrism) and it has the examples: **Eurocentrism** and **ecocentrism**.

Comment: Okay. I've got what is centrism.  But did the speaker criticise "the split decision amounted to a reassertion of centrism" or approve it?

Comment: @NewPlanet They asserted it. How they intended the assertion to be taken is a question only they can answer.

Comment: Please edit the question. Comments are not answers. :) For one thing, they cannot be voted on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The split decision amounted to a reassertion of centrism.

"Centrism" is midway between the political right and left, or between conservatism and liberalism. It means that extremism on either side has been rejected by the election. A "split decision" means that the election wasn't very strongly in favor of either side.

[Merriam-Webster "split decision"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/split%20decision)

> a decision in a boxing match reflecting a division of opinion among the referee and judges